# On Centos Linux, how to install Python package 'readline' using pip?

Tags: python, installation, centos, pip, readline

Using the regular command `sudo pip install readline` I got an error

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Ax57Qh/readline/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KRvGg7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Ax57Qh/readline
```

The complete console output is

```
sudo pip install readline
[sudo] password for qazwsx:
Collecting readline
  Using cached readline-6.2.4.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: readline
  Running setup.py install for readline
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Ax57Qh/readline/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KRvGg7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    readline-6.2/
    readline-6.2/doc/
    readline-6.2/doc/Makefile.in
    readline-6.2/doc/texinfo.tex
    readline-6.2/doc/version.texi
    readline-6.2/doc/fdl.texi
    readline-6.2/doc/rlman.texi
    readline-6.2/doc/rltech.texi
    readline-6.2/doc/rluser.texi
    readline-6.2/doc/rluserman.texi
    readline-6.2/doc/history.texi
    readline-6.2/doc/hstech.texi
    readline-6.2/doc/hsuser.texi
    readline-6.2/doc/readline.3
    readline-6.2/doc/history.3
    readline-6.2/doc/texi2dvi
    readline-6.2/doc/texi2html
    readline-6.2/doc/readline.ps
    readline-6.2/doc/history.ps
    readline-6.2/doc/rluserman.ps
    readline-6.2/doc/readline.dvi
    readline-6.2/doc/history.dvi
    readline-6.2/doc/rluserman.dvi
    readline-6.2/doc/readline.info
    readline-6.2/doc/history.info
    readline-6.2/doc/rluserman.info
    readline-6.2/doc/readline.html
    readline-6.2/doc/history.html
    readline-6.2/doc/rluserman.html
    readline-6.2/doc/readline.0
    readline-6.2/doc/history.0
    readline-6.2/doc/readline_3.ps
    readline-6.2/doc/history_3.ps
    readline-6.2/doc/history.pdf
    readline-6.2/doc/readline.pdf
    readline-6.2/doc/rluserman.pdf
    readline-6.2/examples/
    readline-6.2/examples/autoconf/
    readline-6.2/examples/autoconf/BASH_CHECK_LIB_TERMCAP
    readline-6.2/examples/autoconf/RL_LIB_READLINE_VERSION
    readline-6.2/examples/autoconf/wi_LIB_READLINE
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/ChangeLog
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/Makefile.in
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/README
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/config.h.in
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/configure
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/configure.in
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/extern.h
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/os.h
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/pty.c
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/rlfe.c
    readline-6.2/examples/rlfe/screen.h
    readline-6.2/examples/Makefile.in
    readline-6.2/examples/excallback.c
    readline-6.2/examples/fileman.c
    readline-6.2/examples/manexamp.c
    readline-6.2/examples/readlinebuf.h
    readline-6.2/examples/rl-fgets.c
    readline-6.2/examples/rlcat.c
    readline-6.2/examples/rlevent.c
    readline-6.2/examples/rltest.c
    readline-6.2/examples/rl.c
    readline-6.2/examples/rlptytest.c
    readline-6.2/examples/rlversion.c
    readline-6.2/examples/histexamp.c
    readline-6.2/examples/Inputrc
    readline-6.2/examples/rlwrap-0.30.tar.gz
    readline-6.2/support/
    readline-6.2/support/config.guess
    readline-6.2/support/config.rpath
    readline-6.2/support/config.sub
    readline-6.2/support/install.sh
    readline-6.2/support/mkdirs
    readline-6.2/support/mkdist
    readline-6.2/support/mkinstalldirs
    readline-6.2/support/shobj-conf
    readline-6.2/support/shlib-install
    readline-6.2/support/wcwidth.c
    readline-6.2/shlib/
    readline-6.2/shlib/Makefile.in
    readline-6.2/COPYING
    readline-6.2/README
    readline-6.2/MANIFEST
    readline-6.2/INSTALL
    readline-6.2/CHANGELOG
    readline-6.2/CHANGES
    readline-6.2/NEWS
    readline-6.2/USAGE
    readline-6.2/aclocal.m4
    readline-6.2/config.h.in
    readline-6.2/configure
    readline-6.2/configure.in
    readline-6.2/Makefile.in
    readline-6.2/ansi_stdlib.h
    readline-6.2/chardefs.h
    readline-6.2/history.h
    readline-6.2/histlib.h
    readline-6.2/keymaps.h
    readline-6.2/posixdir.h
    readline-6.2/posixjmp.h
    readline-6.2/readline.h
    readline-6.2/posixselect.h
    readline-6.2/posixstat.h
    readline-6.2/rlconf.h
    readline-6.2/rldefs.h
    readline-6.2/rlmbutil.h
    readline-6.2/rlprivate.h
    readline-6.2/rlshell.h
    readline-6.2/rlstdc.h
    readline-6.2/rltty.h
    readline-6.2/rltypedefs.h
    readline-6.2/rlwinsize.h
    readline-6.2/tcap.h
    readline-6.2/tilde.h
    readline-6.2/xmalloc.h
    readline-6.2/bind.c
    readline-6.2/callback.c
    readline-6.2/compat.c
    readline-6.2/complete.c
    readline-6.2/display.c
    readline-6.2/emacs_keymap.c
    readline-6.2/funmap.c
    readline-6.2/input.c
    readline-6.2/isearch.c
    readline-6.2/keymaps.c
    readline-6.2/kill.c
    readline-6.2/macro.c
    readline-6.2/mbutil.c
    readline-6.2/misc.c
    readline-6.2/nls.c
    readline-6.2/parens.c
    readline-6.2/readline.c
    readline-6.2/rltty.c
    readline-6.2/savestring.c
    readline-6.2/search.c
    readline-6.2/shell.c
    readline-6.2/signals.c
    readline-6.2/terminal.c
    readline-6.2/text.c
    readline-6.2/tilde.c
    readline-6.2/undo.c
    readline-6.2/util.c
    readline-6.2/vi_keymap.c
    readline-6.2/vi_mode.c
    readline-6.2/xfree.c
    readline-6.2/xmalloc.c
    readline-6.2/history.c
    readline-6.2/histexpand.c
    readline-6.2/histfile.c
    readline-6.2/histsearch.c
    readline-6.2/patchlevel
    patching file vi_mode.c
    patching file callback.c
    patching file support/shobj-conf
    patching file patchlevel
    patching file input.c
    patching file patchlevel
    patching file vi_mode.c
    patching file patchlevel
    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

    Beginning configuration for readline-6.2 for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking minix/config.h usability... no
    checking minix/config.h presence... no
    checking for minix/config.h... no
    checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
    checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
    checking for function prototypes... yes
    checking whether char is unsigned... no
    checking for working volatile... yes
    checking return type of signal handlers... void
    checking for size_t... yes
    checking for ssize_t... yes
    checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
    checking whether stat file-mode macros are broken... no
    checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
    checking for library containing opendir... none required
    checking for fcntl... yes
    checking for kill... yes
    checking for lstat... yes
    checking for memmove... yes
    checking for putenv... yes
    checking for select... yes
    checking for setenv... yes
    checking for setlocale... yes
    checking for strcasecmp... yes
    checking for strpbrk... yes
    checking for tcgetattr... yes
    checking for vsnprintf... yes
    checking for isascii... yes
    checking for isxdigit... yes
    checking for getpwent... yes
    checking for getpwnam... yes
    checking for getpwuid... yes
    checking for working strcoll... yes
    checking fcntl.h usability... yes
    checking fcntl.h presence... yes
    checking for fcntl.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
    checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
    checking varargs.h usability... no
    checking varargs.h presence... no
    checking for varargs.h... no
    checking stdarg.h usability... yes
    checking stdarg.h presence... yes
    checking for stdarg.h... yes
    checking for string.h... (cached) yes
    checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
    checking limits.h usability... yes
    checking limits.h presence... yes
    checking for limits.h... yes
    checking locale.h usability... yes
    checking locale.h presence... yes
    checking for locale.h... yes
    checking pwd.h usability... yes
    checking pwd.h presence... yes
    checking for pwd.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... (cached) yes
    checking termcap.h usability... no
    checking termcap.h presence... no
    checking for termcap.h... no
    checking termios.h usability... yes
    checking termios.h presence... yes
    checking for termios.h... yes
    checking termio.h usability... yes
    checking termio.h presence... yes
    checking for termio.h... yes
    checking sys/pte.h usability... no
    checking sys/pte.h presence... no
    checking for sys/pte.h... no
    checking sys/stream.h usability... no
    checking sys/stream.h presence... no
    checking for sys/stream.h... no
    checking sys/select.h usability... yes
    checking sys/select.h presence... yes
    checking for sys/select.h... yes
    checking sys/file.h usability... yes
    checking sys/file.h presence... yes
    checking for sys/file.h... yes
    checking for sys/ptem.h... no
    checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
    checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
    checking for type of signal functions... posix
    checking if signal handlers must be reinstalled when invoked... no
    checking for presence of POSIX-style sigsetjmp/siglongjmp... present
    checking for lstat... yes
    checking whether or not strcoll and strcmp differ... no
    checking whether the ctype macros accept non-ascii characters... yes
    checking whether getpw functions are declared in pwd.h... yes
    checking whether termios.h defines TIOCGWINSZ... no
    checking whether sys/ioctl.h defines TIOCGWINSZ... yes
    checking for sig_atomic_t in signal.h... yes
    checking whether signal handlers are of type void... yes
    checking for TIOCSTAT in sys/ioctl.h... no
    checking for FIONREAD in sys/ioctl.h... yes
    checking for speed_t in sys/types.h... no
    checking for struct winsize in sys/ioctl.h and termios.h... sys/ioctl.h
    checking for struct dirent.d_ino... yes
    checking for struct dirent.d_fileno... yes
    checking for tgetent... no
    checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
    checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no
    checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
    checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
    checking which library has the termcap functions... using gnutermcap
    checking wctype.h usability... yes
    checking wctype.h presence... yes
    checking for wctype.h... yes
    checking wchar.h usability... yes
    checking wchar.h presence... yes
    checking for wchar.h... yes
    checking langinfo.h usability... yes
    checking langinfo.h presence... yes
    checking for langinfo.h... yes
    checking for mbrlen... yes
    checking for mbscasecmp... no
    checking for mbscmp... no
    checking for mbsnrtowcs... yes
    checking for mbsrtowcs... yes
    checking for mbschr... no
    checking for wcrtomb... yes
    checking for wcscoll... yes
    checking for wcsdup... yes
    checking for wcwidth... yes
    checking for wctype... yes
    checking for wcswidth... yes
    checking whether mbrtowc and mbstate_t are properly declared... yes
    checking for iswlower... yes
    checking for iswupper... yes
    checking for towlower... yes
    checking for towupper... yes
    checking for iswctype... yes
    checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... yes
    checking for wchar_t in wchar.h... yes
    checking for wctype_t in wctype.h... yes
    checking for wint_t in wctype.h... yes
    checking configuration for building shared libraries... supported
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating Makefile
    config.status: creating doc/Makefile
    config.status: creating examples/Makefile
    config.status: creating shlib/Makefile
    config.status: creating config.h
    config.status: executing default commands
    rm -f readline.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O readline.c
    rm -f vi_mode.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O vi_mode.c
    rm -f funmap.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O funmap.c
    rm -f keymaps.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O keymaps.c
    rm -f parens.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O parens.c
    rm -f search.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O search.c
    rm -f rltty.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O rltty.c
    rm -f complete.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O complete.c
    rm -f bind.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O bind.c
    rm -f isearch.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O isearch.c
    rm -f display.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O display.c
    rm -f signals.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O signals.c
    rm -f util.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O util.c
    rm -f kill.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O kill.c
    rm -f undo.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O undo.c
    rm -f macro.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O macro.c
    rm -f input.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O input.c
    rm -f callback.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O callback.c
    rm -f terminal.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O terminal.c
    rm -f text.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O text.c
    rm -f nls.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O nls.c
    rm -f misc.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O misc.c
    rm -f compat.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O compat.c
    rm -f xfree.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O xfree.c
    rm -f xmalloc.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O xmalloc.c
    rm -f history.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O history.c
    rm -f histexpand.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O histexpand.c
    rm -f histfile.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O histfile.c
    rm -f histsearch.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O histsearch.c
    rm -f shell.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O shell.c
    rm -f mbutil.o
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O mbutil.c
    rm -f tilde.o
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -DREADLINE_LIBRARY -c ./tilde.c
    rm -f libreadline.a
    ar cr libreadline.a readline.o vi_mode.o funmap.o keymaps.o parens.o search.o rltty.o complete.o bind.o isearch.o display.o signals.o util.o kill.o undo.o macro.o input.o callback.o terminal.o text.o nls.o misc.o compat.o xfree.o xmalloc.o history.o histexpand.o histfile.o histsearch.o shell.o mbutil.o tilde.o
    test -n "ranlib" && ranlib libreadline.a
    rm -f libhistory.a
    ar cr libhistory.a history.o histexpand.o histfile.o histsearch.o shell.o mbutil.o xmalloc.o xfree.o
    test -n "ranlib" && ranlib libhistory.a
    test -d shlib || mkdir shlib
    ( cd shlib ; make  all )
    make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/pip-build-Ax57Qh/readline/rl/readline-lib/shlib'
    rm -f readline.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o readline.o ../readline.c
    mv readline.o readline.so
    rm -f vi_mode.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o vi_mode.o ../vi_mode.c
    mv vi_mode.o vi_mode.so
    rm -f funmap.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o funmap.o ../funmap.c
    mv funmap.o funmap.so
    rm -f keymaps.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o keymaps.o ../keymaps.c
    mv keymaps.o keymaps.so
    rm -f parens.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o parens.o ../parens.c
    mv parens.o parens.so
    rm -f search.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o search.o ../search.c
    mv search.o search.so
    rm -f rltty.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o rltty.o ../rltty.c
    mv rltty.o rltty.so
    rm -f complete.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o complete.o ../complete.c
    mv complete.o complete.so
    rm -f bind.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o bind.o ../bind.c
    mv bind.o bind.so
    rm -f isearch.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o isearch.o ../isearch.c
    mv isearch.o isearch.so
    rm -f display.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o display.o ../display.c
    mv display.o display.so
    rm -f signals.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o signals.o ../signals.c
    mv signals.o signals.so
    rm -f util.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o util.o ../util.c
    mv util.o util.so
    rm -f kill.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o kill.o ../kill.c
    mv kill.o kill.so
    rm -f undo.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o undo.o ../undo.c
    mv undo.o undo.so
    rm -f macro.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o macro.o ../macro.c
    mv macro.o macro.so
    rm -f input.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o input.o ../input.c
    mv input.o input.so
    rm -f callback.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o callback.o ../callback.c
    mv callback.o callback.so
    rm -f terminal.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o terminal.o ../terminal.c
    mv terminal.o terminal.so
    rm -f text.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o text.o ../text.c
    mv text.o text.so
    rm -f nls.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o nls.o ../nls.c
    mv nls.o nls.so
    rm -f misc.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o misc.o ../misc.c
    mv misc.o misc.so
    rm -f xmalloc.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o xmalloc.o ../xmalloc.c
    mv xmalloc.o xmalloc.so
    rm -f xfree.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o xfree.o ../xfree.c
    mv xfree.o xfree.so
    rm -f history.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o history.o ../history.c
    mv history.o history.so
    rm -f histexpand.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o histexpand.o ../histexpand.c
    mv histexpand.o histexpand.so
    rm -f histfile.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o histfile.o ../histfile.c
    mv histfile.o histfile.so
    rm -f histsearch.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o histsearch.o ../histsearch.c
    mv histsearch.o histsearch.so
    rm -f shell.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o shell.o ../shell.c
    mv shell.o shell.so
    rm -f mbutil.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o mbutil.o ../mbutil.c
    mv mbutil.o mbutil.so
    rm -f tilde.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -DREADLINE_LIBRARY -c -o tilde.o ../tilde.c
    mv tilde.o tilde.so
    rm -f compat.so
    gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DNEED_EXTERN_PC -fPIC -I. -I.. -I.. -DRL_LIBRARY_VERSION='"6.2"' -g -O -fPIC -o compat.o ../compat.c
    mv compat.o compat.so
    rm -f libreadline.so.6.2
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libreadline.so.6.2 -L./lib/termcap -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,-soname,`basename libreadline.so.6.2 .2` -o libreadline.so.6.2 readline.so vi_mode.so funmap.so keymaps.so parens.so search.so rltty.so complete.so bind.so isearch.so display.so signals.so util.so kill.so undo.so macro.so input.so callback.so terminal.so text.so nls.so misc.so xmalloc.so xfree.so history.so histexpand.so histfile.so histsearch.so shell.so mbutil.so tilde.so compat.so
    rm -f libhistory.so.6.2
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libhistory.so.6.2 -L./lib/termcap -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,-soname,`basename libhistory.so.6.2 .2` -o libhistory.so.6.2 history.so histexpand.so histfile.so histsearch.so shell.so mbutil.so xmalloc.so xfree.so
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-build-Ax57Qh/readline/rl/readline-lib/shlib'

    ============ Building the readline library ============


    ============ Building the readline extension module ============

    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'readline' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_RL_CALLBACK -DHAVE_RL_CATCH_SIGNAL -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_DISPLAY_MATCHES_HOOK -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_SUPPRESS_APPEND -DHAVE_RL_PRE_INPUT_HOOK -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Modules/2.x/readline.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o -Wno-strict-prototypes
    Modules/2.x/readline.c:8:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Ax57Qh/readline/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KRvGg7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Ax57Qh/readline
```

**Update**: adding path to `$CPATH` does NOT help

```
-bash-4.2$ locate Python.h
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
-bash-4.2$ echo $CPATH

-bash-4.2$ export CPATH=/usr/include/python2.7/
-bash-4.2$ echo $CPATH
/usr/include/python2.7/
```

and I still get the *same* error running `sudo pip install readline`:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-NP1WUS/readline/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-9Uamrv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NP1WUS/readline
```

Then the said file no longer exist in tmp/:

```
-bash-4.2$ ls -la /tmp/pip-build-*
ls: cannot access /tmp/pip-build-*: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try installing `sudo yum install python-devel ` first

Answer (score 2):

Don't know for sure but:

Try installing `sudo yum install python-devel`

EDIT:
Can you check if the directory /usr/include/python2.7 actually exists? Looks like gcc can't find the libraries for Python.

Comment: I have verified that `/usr/include/python2.7` exists indeed.

Comment: Can you clean the /tmp folder and run the build again? Are you sure you get the same error? E.g. 'Python.h' not found and not some other library?

Comment: Check the edited update in the original post after "**Update**".

Answer (score 1):

This is really a Linux/gcc issue than a python/pip question. Also the more compact your question is the better if you look at the output the very end of that wall of text is all that is important

The installation failed when pip is finished the configure step and starts the compilation. The compiler cant find the `Python.h` file which is the header file that contains a lot of the definitions the source code for the plugin will use.

The long gcc command that failed has this flag added `-I/usr/include/python2.7`

You can start by looking there to see if that path even exists, and if it does does it contain the python headers. On my system I have a whole bunch of python versions installed for various reasons, but in general  my environment is configured so that the environmental variable `$CPATH` will have `/usr/python/active/include` where active is a link to the correct version. So if I am working with python2.7 this points to `/usr/local/python/2.7/include`:

From the GCC docs on environmental variables:

> CPATH
>
> C_INCLUDE_PATH
>
> CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
>
> OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
>
> Each variable's value is a list of directories separated by a special character, much like PATH, in which to look for header files. The special character, PATH_SEPARATOR, is target-dependent and determined at GCC build time. For Microsoft Windows-based targets it is a semicolon, and for almost all other targets it is a colon.
>
> CPATH specifies a list of directories to be searched as if specified with -I, but after any paths given with -I options on the command line. This environment variable is used regardless of which language is being preprocessed.

You can fix this issue by first, locating the directory where the relevant files are. Try finding the python executable `which python` it will point to something like this `/some/path/.../bin/python` if the path before `.../bin` contains a `/pythonXX/` folder the headers should be in `/path/to/pythonXX/include` if it does not then they should be in `/some/path/.../include/python/include`

It can vary based on if there are many versions of python installed, if you are working on a personal workstation or on a larger cluster, or the preference/practices of whoever is your admin (or was when it was set up ) your system. Either way if you cant find it try `locate Python.h`

When you do find the file you can just add it to the CPATH variable and try again.

```
export CPATH=/the/path/to/this/file:$CPATH
```

and try again. this problem will happen the next time you try so you might want to add that line (without the export) to your .bashrc file

Comment: So why the configuring of `$CPATH` is necessary to be done manually and there is no indication for an average user to do that?

Comment: Well it should be that when python was installed these headers were added to the global include paths.  It looks like from your errors that this wasn't done because python may have been installed in a non-standard way.  In short normally this isn't something you should have to configure in order for pip to compile packages for you. Without sitting down and looking at your python installation directories and the output of `printenv` I couldn't tell you how to go about fixing it but locating the directory and adding to the `$CPATH` should fix your problem here.